# Meaning of "squeeze the limit"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, euphemisms

I was watching a movie and the phrase "squeeze the limit" came to my attention (if I heard it right).  I have never heard the phrase before, and according to the Japanese subtitle, it seem to mean "take a sh*t" (excuse me for not knowing the proper euphemism), and the man who said the phrase went to the bathroom.  Is this a common phrase to euphemize "take a s..."?  Do native speakers of English usually understand what that means?

Comment: I haven't heard it either. To me it suggests something mathematical.

Comment: Me neither. It would help to know what the movie was; whether it was an English-language movie (or, for example, dubbed into English and then translated again in subtitles), and more useful still would be a link to a clip (timed to land at the right place in the film).

Comment: That said, ***squeeze the lemon*** has made it into [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=squeeze%20the%20lemon) and that does seem a reasonable fit for the question. Urban Dictionary is a good source of information on this sort of slang.

Comment: You are almost certainly faced with translation error, possibly even an auto-translation error.  Such things are very common.  This is because any given word in one language may cover a different range of meanings than any one word in another, even though they may have one point of synonymity.  It is thus easy for an algorithm or a non-native translator to go to the wrong word or phrase.  Looking it up in an online dictionary, I notice, for example, that one Japanese word for 'bottom' is 'shita'.  In English, 'bottom' can be called ones 'rear end'.  'End' - 'limit'?  I bet it was a boob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently ***squeeze the lemon*** would fit this:

> to relieve one self by urinating. Fluid colours may be the same as a lemon being squeezed.
>
> > be right back, have to go *squeeze the lemon* and *lay a cable* ([qv](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lay%20a%20cable))
>
> — [John-do](https://www.urbandictionary.com/author.php?author=John-do) in [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=squeeze%20the%20lemon), 2006 [spelling corrected]

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I heard it (or remembered it) wrong -- I double-checked the movie and the man actually was saying "squeeze the lemon."  BTW, the movie was "Get Smart" :)